# Error when adding scoped dependency and different 'arity'

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection

I'm attempting to register the following:

`services.AddScoped(typeof(IReadRepository<>), typeof(EfRepository<,>));`

However I'm receiving this error message:

*Error: Arity of open generic service type 'Harmony.Data.Common.Abstractions.IReadRepository`1[T]' does not equal arity of open generic implementation type 'Harmony.Data.SqlServer.EfRepository`2[T,TContext]'. (Parameter 'descriptors')*

For the resolved to type, the first type param is to be passed as the type argument to IReadRepository. The second param is of type DbContext which has already been registered.

Is there some other trick I'm missing here?

Thank you!